# How can I compile C program on Openstack VM running on Ubuntu

Tags: virtual-machine, openstack

I have an OpenStack cloud system with 3 servers and two VMs on my compute node. Everything is working fine. I can reach all the nodes from the VMs and can ping internet from the VMs as well, this means, there is no connectivity issue at all. My problem is I want to run some loading balancing C codes on these VMs but I do not have C or C++ compiler. How do I install C compiler on these VMs or is there another way around this? Please note that these VMs were created using the recommended Ubuntu image and everything is working fine. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a C/C++ compiler on your VM you can simply login and install it.

> sudo apt install build-essential

Alternatively you can pre-install a compiler when building the standard image.

Comment: It seems you did not understand the details in my question. Before I asked the question, I was able login into the VM through ssh and through the dashboard. No command is working despite using the recommended Ubuntu image during the instance creation. Can you describe how to pre-install a compiler when building an image? If I have this description, I think this option might work.